# Entity Framework map SQL Table using Table Annotation Attribute

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

I am using EF 6, Database First Approach. so i am creating all the Domain objects manually. I want to map these Classes with the my SQL Server Tables. if i do the below(Within my DbContext) then my code works...

```
public virtual DbSet<countries> countries { get; set; }
```

But problem is, i rather not do this, since database has many tables and will keep on growing.

I read about using Table Attribute to map a table withg a Sql Table, however it is not working and throwing the Enityt not found/mapped error.

Below is my GenericRepo, in which I have one Method GetAll().

```
public abstract class GenericRepository<C, T> :
    IGenericRepository<T> where T : class where C : DbContext, new()
{

    private C _entities = new C();
    public C Context
    {

        get { return _entities; }
        set { _entities = value; }
    }

    public virtual IQueryable<T> GetAll()
    {

        IQueryable<T> query = _entities.Set<T>();
         return query;

    }
```

Below is my DbCopntext

```
public class PhotoContext: DbContext
{
    public PhotoContext()
    : base("PhotoDatabase")
    {
    }


    // if I unComment this, then Code Works
    //public virtual DbSet<countries> countries { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
    }

}
```

Below is my County Repo, which simply inherits from Generic Repo

```
public class countriesRepository: GenericRepository<PhotoContext, Models.DomainModels.countries>
{
}
```

Below is my Domain Object, my Sql Server has a Table called "Countries" as well. So i am annotating it with the Table attribute,

```
[Table("countries")]
public class countries
{
    [Column("Country_Name")]
    public string Country_Name { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column("CountryCode")]
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    [Column("sort")]
    public int sort { get; set; }
}
```

And finally, this is how i am calling the Repo.

```
        var a = new countriesRepository();
        var r = a.GetAll().ToList();
```

I get the Error.

> **System.InvalidOperationException: 'The entity type countries is not part of the model for the current context.'**

Comment: You will need a `DbSet` for all tables in your database.

Comment: Same as I mentioned in my example above? any easier way to include all tables?

Comment: Hi, take a look to this article which explain how dynamically building a model with Code First https://romiller.com/2012/03/26/dynamically-building-a-model-with-code-first/, be aware that this aproach can have performance impacts.

Comment: It's called maintaining your code. When the tables change you update your context, otherwise how would your code know what to use for the application and what not to use.

Comment: Also, the Table attribute specifies how the code will map to the table in the sense of how the SQL for creating the table for that entity will be generated. This is when you're breaking from the default EF naming standard and thus has nothing to do with auto-populating your context for you.

Comment: understood, now is there any easier way to map all tables to my models within my dbContext?. I imported all SQL tables as POCO into my project.

Comment: When you reverse engineer (Code First From Database) it will create the POCOs and a class that contains all the DbSets and fluent code. Also, you only need the Table and Column attributes if the table or column name is different than the class or property name.